# Choosing between Drawing and Shape in WPF

Tags: wpf, graphics, 2d

I am not quite sure about the differences between the classes `System.Windows.Media.Drawing` and `System.Windows.Shapes.Shape`. They both expose functionality related to 2D graphics in WPF. When would you choose one in your WPF application, and when would you choose the other?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `Shape` inherits from [FrameworkElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx) and is therefore a high level object which provides features such as hit-testing, styling, layout and data binding. In contrast a [Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawing.aspx) does not inherit from `FrameworkElemet` and doesn't support any of these features.  As the documentation mentions a `Drawing` is useful for lightweight visual objects. If you are creating a complex brush to use to paint areas or a background a DrawingBrush would be very efficient.

Drawings can combine text, video, images and [Geometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.aspx) objects (another light weight class) to create complex but very efficient and fast drawings.

In short a `Drawing` is a low-level alternative to a `Shape`.
As for use cases, it depends.

- If you have to animate or do any sort of binding you would use Shapes.
- If you are creating brushes or complex clip arts/vector graphics you would probably use Drawings.
- Also, if you draw things by overriding `OnRender` you would mostly use Geometries.

A `Drawing` is also `Freezable` and can thus be shared among threads (assuming it is frozen).